# Notation for 8va on the repeat

Tags: piano, notation, repeats, ottava

In piano music sometimes there is a section that is repeated, and on the repeat one (or both) hands are to play an octave up (or down).

I've seen this notated in English in the following form:

> *2<sup>nd</sup> time RH 8<sup>va</sup>*

- But is there similar notation in the common music language Italian?

I imagine it might be rendered as something like:

> *V2 m.d. 8<sup>va</sup>* (*Volta seconda mano destra all'ottava*)

But this is just a guess, is this good music-Italian?

---

When it's for both hands, such as:

> *2<sup>nd</sup> time play both hands 8<sup>va</sup>*

I'm tempted to write something like:

> *V2 e.m. 8<sup>va</sup>* (*Volta seconda entrambe le mani all'ottava*)

Again this is just a guess, as I don't speak Italian.

- Are there examples of this sort of notation in the repertoire?
- Is there another way to notate that on the repeat, the notes for one (or both) hands are to be played an octave up (or down)?

---

#### Update:

I've found a similar notation in Bartók's *Mikrokosmos, No. 113*:

[image: Bartók's Mikrokosmos No. 113 m. 4, showing "la IIa volta ..." notation]

Here, the following is used to show a change of dynamic on the repeat:

> *la II<sup>a</sup> volta meno f*

This seems to generally agree with both both @AakashM's and @Old_Brixtonian's answers (below).  Though notably it uses a capital roman numeral to abbreviate *seconda*.

The Dolmetsch dictionary entry for [*II<sup>da</sup>*](https://www.dolmetsch.com/defs0.htm) agrees with @AakashM's ordinal abbreviation of *II<sup>da</sup>* rather than Bartók's *II<sup>a</sup>*.

---

However, I am still not sure how best to indicate which hand/hands the notation is applying to.

- Should I put the marking over each staff that it applies to?
  This would make hand indication superfluous, but an *8<sup>va</sup>* over a bass clef seems kinda yuk.
- Or should I use *m.d*/*m.s.* and possibly *e.m.* or *d.m.*?
  This would make it unambiguous as to whether it applies to one hand or both.  But perhaps I shouldn't abbreviate *entrambe le mani* / *le due mani*?

I would find it helpful to see a score that uses this (or similar notation) for a change of octave on a repeat.

Comment: Some adjectives (usually) precede the noun, including prima, seconda, etc.  We don't speak after all of a _donna prima._  For both hands, the traditional approach in the absence of repeats is to indicate _8va_ separately on each staff.  I'm not sure how helpful that is here.

Comment: @phoog Okay, good point about the word order (I don't know why I messed that up).  Placing an _8va_ above a bass clef staff seem ugly though.

Comment: I most commonly see this kind of "2nd time 8va" notation in ragtime music. ...Guess that's why we don't tend to see this instruction in Italian.

Comment: @phoog I think I got the word order the wrong way around because I was following the pattern of "Tempo primo".

Comment: Related: [Octave changes on 2nd time](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/24884/octave-changes-on-2nd-time)

Answer (score 5):

If your score strictly separates the hand's activities between the staves, as piano music tends to, then a simple *2da volta 8va* above the top staff should suffice, to my mind.

<sub>2da being short for *second**a***, since volt**a** is feminine; also note that [*second-* goes before the noun, to mean 'second'](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/secondo#Adjective)</sub>

Comment: I don't really understand the first half of your sentence, can you reword it to make it more clear please?  Also, are you saying that _2da volta 8va_ above the top staff would/should be interpreted as applying to both staves?

Comment: I meant that usually in piano music the right hand plays the notes on the top staff and the left hand plays the notes on the bottom staff. Given that you want to raise *both* hands the second time, I'd say you also want some wording for 'both hands', as in [Old Brixtonian's answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/123514), as normally *8va* would only apply to the staff it's written for.

Comment: Ah right, yeah the right hand is in the top staff and the left hand is in the bottom staff.

Answer (score 2):

In proper Italian it would be

**la seconda volta entrambe le mani un'ottava più alta**

But *entrambe* -"both" - might confuse people: it's rarely seen in music. So

**la seconda volta le due mani un'ottava più alta**

might be safer.

Do you need to bother with that verbiage though? It would be much simpler to say,

**2nd x both hands 8va**.

Comment: I'll definitely be abbreviating it as much as possible:  
_la IIda volta e.m. 8va_ or _la IIda volta d.m. 8va_ both seems reasonable, but I was hoping there would be a standard.